# Should I place the parameter storage class specifier in the function definition or in both the declaration and definition?

Tags: c, declaration, definition, c89

I'm working on porting some old K&R code to ANSI C, so I'm writing missing function prototype declarations. A lot of the function definitions have parameters with the register storage class, but I'm not sure if the register storage class specifier can be omitted in the function prototype?

With and without the register storage class specific declaration, the code compiles correctly (I tried GCC, VC++ and Watcom C). I could not find any information in the ISO/ANSI C89 standard on what is the correct way to do - is it OK if I just put the register keyword in the function definition?

```
int add(register int x, register int y); 

int add(register int x, register int y)
{
  return x+y;
}
```

This also builds correctly:

```
int add(int x, int y);

int add(register int x, register int y)
{
   return x+y;
}
```

I want to make sure that the register storage specifier is really taken into account, according to the standard (my target is to compile using a very old compiler where this storage class specifier is important). Are both OK and it's just a question of coding style, or not?

Comment: What's the target compiler / system?

Comment: Take a look here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3 *The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is register.*

Comment: And from the logical point of view I would imagine that the specifier is needed in both, as the *call* is generated based on the prototype, while the implementation is based on the definition. So  if the caller will push the arguments to the stack while the implementation might expect them in registers - you might have a mismatch. But it is really depending on the ABI.

Comment: Storage class is not a factor in determining whether types are compatible. Therefore, the type of a function declared with register should be compatible with the type of a function declared without register, if they are otherwise compatible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What is the reason for this `register` exception in the standard?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's not an exception. Storage classes are never included in type information. `auto int x;` , `static int x;`, and `register int x;` all have type `int`.

Comment: @PSkocik Why `auto` can't be included but `register` can (well, `static` would not make sense)?

Comment: @EugeneSh That's an interesting quirk I hadn't noticed! I don't know why but I think nobody uses `auto` so nobody noticed it could also be harmlessly allowed in parameter declaration.

Comment: @dbush: I am actually working on modernizing the Amsterdam compiler toolkit (ACK), so its multi platform.

Comment: Guessing it's a relic of the fact that `auto` predates type specifiers altogether (it was in B) and was added to mark a statement as being a variable declaration; variables named in the parameter list don't need this, so there's no ambiguity and no compiler ever thought to implement it. The fact that it later indicated storage class is probably a bit of a historical artifact to rationalize why we need a declaration-marking statement now that we have type names in the language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key provision is that every declaration of the function must specify a compatible type for it.  That requires compatible return types, and, for declarations such as yours that contain parameter lists, compatible type for each pair of corresponding parameters.

The question then becomes whether storage-class specifiers differentiate types.  They do not, though the standard says that indirectly, by omission of storage-class specifiers from its discussion of type derivation.  The property specified by a storage-class specifier in an object's declaration is therefore separate from that object's type.

Moreover, C89 [specifically says](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.4.3)

> The storage-class specifier in the declaration specifiers for a parameter declaration, if present, **is ignored** unless the declared parameter is one of the members of the parameter type list for a function definition.

(emphasis added).  A function definition is a declaration accompanied by a function body, as opposed to a forward declaration, so your two codes have identical semantics.

> With and without the register storage class specific declaration, the
>   code compiles correctly (I tried gcc, VC++ and Watcom), I could not
>   find any information in the ISO/ANSI C89 standard on what is the
>   correct way to do, or is it ok if i just put the register keyword in
>   the function definition?

Personally, I would be inclined to make each forward declaration identical to the declaration in the corresponding function definition.  This is never wrong if the function definition itself is correct.

HOWEVER,

1. The `register` keyword is a relic.  Compilers are not obligated to make any attempt at all to actually assign `register` variables to registers, and modern compilers are a lot better than humans at deciding how to assign variables to registers and otherwise to generate fast code anyway.  As long as you're converting old code, I would take the opportunity to remove all appearances of the `register` keyword.
2. C89 is obsolete.  The latest version of the standard is C 2018; C 2011 is widely deployed; and C99 (also, technically, obsolete) is available almost everywhere.  Perhaps there is a good reason for you to target C89, but you should strongly consider instead targeting  C11 or C18, or *at least* C99.

Comment: As replied above, the compiler i am working with is ANSI C89 compatible, and currently the code of it is K&R, so i am trying to "modernize" the code a bit... and then bootstrap it, it does use the register keyword into consideration in its code generator.

Comment: I think, as with other advice given below,the safe bet is to have the register specifier  in both the definition and declaration, and this is what I did, I just wanted to make sure it was a logical choice.

Comment: @CarlEricCodere, it is important to understand what I said about `register`.  The point is not that compilers necessarily don't or shouldn't pay attention to it, but rather that if if they *do*, then it is more likely to cause them to emit worse code than better.  Compilers from the 90's and onward are much better at allocating data to registers effectively than 70s-era compilers were.  They do not need the programmer's help in that regard, so generally the *best* case is that using the `register` keyword is a needless redundancy.

Comment: However, if you do retain the `register` keywords then yes, putting them in both declaration and definition is best and cleanest.

Answer (score 6):

The C89 standard does say this (§ 3.5.4.3 External definitions):

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is `register`.

So, it would appear that while `register` is permissible as a function parameter storage class specifier, I still believe that whether or not this is honored really depends on the architecture and calling convention for the function.

Since you mentioned Watcom and C89, I'm going to assume you're targeting x86-16. The typical calling conventions for x86-16 (`pascal`, `stdcall`, and `cdecl`) all require parameters to be pushed on the stack, not in registers, so I doubt that the keyword would actually modify how the parameters are passed to the function at the call site.

Consider, you have the following function definition:

```
int __stdcall add2(register int x, register int y);
```

The function goes into the object file as `_add2@4` per requirements for stdcall. The @4 indicates how many bytes to remove from the stack at function return. The `ret imm16` (return to calling procedure and pop imm16 bytes from stack) instruction is used in this case.

`add2` will then have the following `ret` at the end:

```
ret 4
```

If 4 bytes were not pushed on the stack at the call site (i.e. because the parameters were actually in registers), your program now has a misaligned stack and crashes.

Comment: From my understanding, unless i am completely wrong, the storage class specifier in the parameter just means that the variable associated with the parameter should be placed in a register (even after the start of the code executes in the routine), it does not necessarily indicate it will be called using register calling conventions, no?

Comment: @CarlEricCodere The standard doesn't actually say anything on that topic - only that the keyword `register` is permissible in the parameter list

Answer (score 6):

Empirically on gcc and clang, the `register` storage class on function params
is behaving the same as top-level qualifiers on params: only the ones in the *definition* (not a previous prototype) count.

(as for top level qualifiers, they're also discarded when type compatibility is considered, i.e., `void f(int);` and `void f(int const);` are compatible prototypes, but storage classes aren't part of types so type compatibility isn't an issue with them in the first place)

From the point of view of a C programmer, the only observable upshot of `register` in C is that the compiler will not let you take the address of the declared object.

When I do:

```
void f(int A, int register B);

void f(int register A, int B) 
{
    /*&A;*/ //doesn't compile => A does have register storage here
    &B; //compiles => B doesn't have register storage here;
        //the register from the previous prototype wasn't considered
}
```

then `&B` compiles, but `&A` doesn't, so only the qualifiers in the *definition* appear to count.

I think that if you do need those `register`, your best bet is to use it consistently in both places (the `register` in prototypes could theoretically modify how calls are made).

Comment: Interesting observation... I guess this is compiler specific in that case.

Comment: @CarlEricCodere I could be wrong but I don't think the standard has wording about how prototypes with different storage classifiers should be combined with the contradicting definition so testing is all there is left. For top level qualifiers (like the last `const` int `int const* const X`) I think it is prescribed that only those in the definition are used in the body. (They don't play a role in the function's type.) IRC last time I checked, `__attributes` (nonstandard extension) and things like `inline`/`_Noreturn` tended to accumulate.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using an old compiler for an odd platform, sometimes just looking at what the compiler does is more important than assuming it will comply perfectly with the C spec.

This means you want to run each variant of your example through the compiler, with the compiler option set to generate assembly instead of an executable.  Look at the assembly, and see if you can tell if it is using registers or not each way.  In gcc, this is the `S` option; for example:

```
gcc myfile.c -S -o myfile.s
```

Answer (score 0):

From C17 standard, **6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers**:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class
>   specifier **register** suggests that access to the object be as fast as
>   possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined.

Imply that the compiler will try, or not depending on compiler, to speed-up parameter access, but doesn't imply any modification to the calling convention (basically no modifications on calling side).

So it should be present in the function definition, but is insignificant in prototype.